# Nested html not being parsed by Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to parse a page with Jsoup, but the html doesn't seem to be parsing correctly.

The general structure is:

```
    <html>
        <head> ... </head>
        <frameset ...>
            <frame ...>
                #document
                    <html> ... </html>
            </frame>
        </frameset>
   </html>
```

When I parse the html and print it with 
`Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); System.out.println(doc.html());` 
 it prints out the outer html (including #document, but not the frames or inner html).

Does anyone know how to get the inner html with Jsoup, or should I consider using a different library?
Thanks.

Edit: Here's the site I'm parsing. I have a subscription to it; don't know if it'll let any of you in.

http://database.asahi.com/library2/login/login.php

After authentication, it will take you to: http://database.asahi.com/library2/main/start.php

Edit 2:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <frameset rows="58,*" border="0">
      <frame name="Header"> </frame>
      <frame name="Introduce">
         #document
            <html>
               <head>hello</head>
               <body>hello again</body>
            </html>
      </frame>
   </frameset>
</html>
```

Then I run:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements elems = doc.select("frameset > frame:last-child");
 // print(elems);
    switch(elems.size()) {
        case 0: break;
        case 1: doc = Jsoup.connect(elems.first().attr("src")).get(); break;
        default: break;
    }

  System.out.println(doc.html());
```

The parsed html (doc.html()):

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  &iuml;&raquo;&iquest;      #document  hello hello again   
 </body>
</html>
```

So it's not even finding `<frameset>`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to parse the nested html:

```
// Fetch the page with frameset
Document doc = Jsoup
               .connect("http://database.asahi.com/library2/login/login.php")
               .get(); // Add login, password etc

// Determine the frame url you want to parse...
// Note: I assume you want to parse the content of the first frame
Elements elts = doc.select("frameset > frame:first-child");
switch (elts.size()) {
    case 0:
        // No frame found ...
    break;

    case 1:
       Element frameElt = elts.first();
       Document frameDoc = Jsoup
                          .connect(frameElt.attr("src"))
                          .get();

       // Add the frameDoc nodes to doc (via frameElt#insertChildren) 
       frameElt.insertChildren(0, frameDoc.childNodes());
    break;

    default:
        // Strange result...
} 

System.out.println(doc.html());
```

Comment: hmm, I'm having some issues with this. It's still incorrectly parsing the html. (see edit)

Comment: @Pushkin In the edit `doc` is overwritten, this is why *"It's still incorrectly parsing the html."*. Use two distinct `Document` instances: one for the frameset (ie `doc`) and one for the desired frame (`frameDoc` for instance).

Comment: isn't that what I want? If I overwrite it and print the new doc's html, it should contains the elements in the <frame>, right?

Comment: @Pushkin You want to use the `insertChildren` method in this case. Check my answer , I have updated it.

Comment: When I parse the html (first line) it throws out the frameset so the html doesn't even have that. This also explains why my elts list is empty. Any workaround?